# How to import war file (maven java project) in Netbeans for changes

Tags: java, netbeans

I got my old deployed war file from glassfish and now i want to import the code in Netbeans and want to update the code. How can i import the war into netbeans as i found it is just having .class files not .java.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You should :

1. use a decompiler to get the java classes
2. Create a new war project in netbeans
3. Add the decompiled java classes decompiled
4. Add all the resources found in the war : application contexts, configuration files, images, html, js, etc ..